# Returning multiple models to view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using `Laravel 5.5` and I am returning two models from a function:

```
public function getDetails($id) {
...
$result = array($instruments->toJson(), $team->toJson());
}
```

Now I would like to load each result in the frontend:

```
 public function details($id)
    {

        $res = $this->getDetails($id);
        $instrument = $res['0']; //instrument
        $team = $res['1']; //team

        Log::info("instrument");
        Log::info($instrument);
        Log::info("team");
        Log::info($team);
        Log::info($team->image);

        return view('details')->with('instrumentUnderEdit', $instrument)->with('teamUnderEdit', $team);
    }
```

My console output looks like the following:

```
[2018-01-14 10:13:22] local.INFO: instrument  
[2018-01-14 10:13:22] local.INFO: {"id":1,"revisions_id":1,"name":"Bitcoin","symbol":"BTC","image":"bitcoin.png","sector":"sdfsf","country_of_origin":"Country of Origin","created_at":"2018-01-03 15:49:23","updated_at":"2018-01-03 15:49:23","revision_status":1}  
[2018-01-14 10:13:22] local.INFO: team  
[2018-01-14 10:13:22] local.INFO: [{"id":1400,"instruments_id":1,"revisions_id":1,"firstname":"adfasdf","lastname":"asdfasd","twitterAccount":"fasdfasdf","created_at":"2018-01-12 20:32:49","updated_at":"2018-01-12 20:32:49","name":"Bitcoin","symbol":"BTC","image":"bitcoin.png","sector":"sdfsf","country_of_origin":"Country of Origin","revision_status":1},{"id":1400,"instruments_id":1,"revisions_id":1,"firstname":"Sathosi","lastname":"Nakomoto","twitterAccount":"www.twitter.com\/Sathoshi","created_at":"2018-01-12 20:32:49","updated_at":"2018-01-12 20:32:49","name":"Bitcoin","symbol":"BTC","image":"bitcoin.png","sector":"sdfsf","country_of_origin":"Country of Origin","revision_status":1},{"id":1401,"instruments_id":1,"revisions_id":1,"firstname":"adfasdf","lastname":"asdfadsf","twitterAccount":"sadfadsf","created_at":"2018-01-12 20:57:05","updated_at":"2018-01-12 20:57:05","name":"Bitcoin","symbol":"BTC","image":"bitcoin.png","sector":"sdfsf","country_of_origin":"Country of Origin","revision_status":1},{"id":1401,"instruments_id":1,"revisions_id":1,"firstname":"Sathosi","lastname":"Nakomoto","twitterAccount":"www.twitter.com\/Sathoshi","created_at":"2018-01-12 20:57:05","updated_at":"2018-01-12 20:57:05","name":"Bitcoin","symbol":"BTC","image":"bitcoin.png","sector":"sdfsf","country_of_origin":"Country of Origin","revision_status":1},{"id":1401,"instruments_id":1,"revisions_id":1,"firstname":"Sathosi","lastname":"Nakomoto","twitterAccount":"www.twitter.com\/Sathoshi","created_at":"2018-01-12 20:57:05","updated_at":"2018-01-12 20:57:05","name":"Bitcoin","symbol":"BTC","image":"bitcoin.png","sector":"sdfsf","country_of_origin":"Country of Origin","revision_status":1}]
```

In my `index.blade.php` file I am trying to load the property as the following:

`<img style="height: 32px; width: 32px;" src="{{ asset('images')}}/{{ $instrumentUnderEdit->image }}" /> {{ $instrumentUnderEdit->name }}`

However, I get the following error:

> [2018-01-14 10:13:22] local.ERROR: Trying to get property of
>   non-object {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Trying to
>   get property of non-object at C:\Users\marcus\Desktop\Coding
>   Projects\demo_laravel_screener\app\Http\Controllers\InstrumentsController.php:203)

Any suggestions why I cannot access in my view the `$instrumentUnderEdit` variable  with `$instrumentUnderEdit->image`?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: provide your complete view code how you get $instrumentUnderEdit?

Comment: What line exactly produces the error?

Comment: Same question you asked yesterday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to use a collection as an object.

Use the `first()` method to get an object:

```
$teamUnderEdit->first()->firstname
```

If you want to display all objects in given collection, iterate over it.

Also, instead of this:

```
$res = $this->getDetails($id);
$instrument = $res['0']; //instrument
$team = $res['1']; //team
```

Use `list()`:

```
list($instrument, $team) = $this->getDetails($id);
```